# How much memory does adding an empty <g> tag to an SVG tag consume?

Tags: svg

Reason I ask is because I found that adding SVG elements to  tags that are higher in the SVG allows them to appear "behind" elements that are added after the  tag. For example (this is from memory):

```
<svg>
    <g id="background">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"></rect>
    </g>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></rect>
</svg>
```

So if you were to add a rect to the background  tag it would appear behind the second rect.

So if you started your drawing by creating this:

```
<svg>
    <g id="layer1"></g>
    <g id="layer2"></g>
    <g id="layer3"></g>
    <g id="layer4"></g>
    <g id="layer5"></g>
    <g id="layer6"></g>
    <g id="layer7"></g>
    <g id="layer8"></g>
    <g id="layer9"></g>
    <g id="layer10"></g>
</svg>
```

You could then move tags around between the  tags to simulate layers.

But how much memory do these  tags take up? Is doing this horribly inefficient?

Comment: On what browser, on what platform, on what version of that browser, 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: A rect in Firefox was around 1K ten years ago. It's probably come down quite a bit since then and a g would be smaller anyway as it has fewer attributes.

Comment: I don't have a specific computer in mind - a typical desktop in use today. If there is such a thing. My website isn't used by mobile browsers much - but the RGraph software could be used by others whose websites do have a high mobile percentage. Sounds like creating 10 <g> tags - ie 10 "layers" - would not be a drain at all.

Comment: What's the performance like with this? Specifically detaching nodes from one <g> tag and appending them to another.

Comment: EDIT: Though I guess I won't be trying to get 50fps per second with this - I can't see it being overly useful in animations.

Comment: The answer to all questions like this is basically "try it and see". It'll be dependent on the environment.  However, as Robert said, it is going to use up very little memory. Not enough to worry about  Not unless you are creating tens of thousands of them.

Comment: Ok, cheers....!